# How can I make a echo in echo in laravel with curly braces?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
{{HTML::decode(link_to_route('showInsList','<button class="btn btn-primary" type=" button"><span class="badge">{{$test->num}}</span> Messungen </button>', array($test->id))) }}
```

I want to show the value of $test->num but it is not working.
What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: well i'm in a foreach-loop and want to generate a button with a badge on it. test->num includes the number i want to use as a badge.

Comment: It reminds me of `Inception`

Comment: Why not just use the `Url` helper then? `<a href="{{ Url::route('showInsList', [ $test->id ]) }}">{{$test->num}}</a>`

Comment: <a href="{{ Url::route('showInsList', [ $test->id ])"><button class="btn btn-primary" type=" button"><span class="badge">{{$test->num}}</span> Messungen </button></a> is this code ok?

Comment: Yes, something similar to that. But, you aren't supposed to have a `button` inside `a` tag. consider simply styling the  `a`  tag to look like a button instead. Stick to valid HTML to avoid headaches with browsers.

Comment: I added an answer for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to simply generate a button with a link, it is much cleaner to just write the HTML and use the `URL` helper. Something like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('showInsList', array($test->id)) }}">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
        <span class="badge">{{ $test->num }}</span>
        Messungen
    </button>
</a>
```

But, you aren't supposed to have `button` inside `a` tag, so you should consider styling the `a` tag to look like a button instead.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('showInsList', array($test->id)) }}">
        <span class="badge">{{ $test->num }}</span>
        Messungen
</a>
```

Try to stick to valid and semantic HTML to avoid headaches with browsers later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{HTML::decode(link_to_route('showInsList','<button class="btn btn-primary" type=" button"><span class="badge">{{$test->num}}</span> Messungen </button>', array($test->id))) }}
```

You have already started echoing your string using the opening curly braces `{{` the first time you've enter it. So you don't need to use the curly braces again on `$test->num`

Try again using the following

```
   {{HTML::decode(link_to_route('showInsList','<button class="btn btn-primary" type=" button"><span class="badge"> $test->num </span> Messungen </button>', array($test->id))) }}
```

The `{{}}` surrounding `$test->num` are gone.